# Paying tuition fees through riba based bank

Tags: halal-haram, riba, fatwa

Is it permissible to pay my tuition fees through a riba-based bank? My school has only one option to pay tuition fees. I only go to the bank and pay the fees to the cashier and they sign my fees card, then transfer the money to my school (maybe they also charge money from my school authority) . Is it permissible for me to pay through this bank?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's permissible. It's only forbidden to take riba or work for a riba bank. Money transfer from, to or inside non-Muslim countries through banks that take riba is common practice although other ways are preferred.